# Remove string after a certain character?

Tags: php, regex, string

How can I remove the remaining part of a string after certain characters like `?, #, &, %, =` in PHP? Any ideas? I tried `preg_replace()`, but I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Update, just realized I read it wrong. You're looking for stuff before, not after. Updated code:

```
$test_string = 'remember?forget';
preg_match('/([^?#&%=]+)/', $test_string, $matches);
$part_before_char = $matches[1];
```

After run, $part_before_char = 'remember'

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$str = "Hello World#somesuffixstr";
preg_match("/^(.*?[?#&%=]).*/", $str, $str);
echo $str[1];
// Should output "Hello World#"
```

About the regex pattern:
 It searches for beginning of string (^), then for any character 0 or more times (which is group #1), then such a symbol like & or %, then any character zero or more times. It replaces the string with the characters matched in group #1.

Answer (score -1):

```
$str = 'mystring#deletedpartofstring';

$str = preg_replace('/[?#&%=].+/', '', $str);
```

Comment: Removed downvote. But character classes don't need vertical bars. Things in character classes are OR'd by default.

Comment: ooh yes, I forgot this, so, I removed the vertical bars now

Comment: The question requires the certain symbol (like % or &) to be included in the remaining string as well.

Comment: He could alter it so it uses a non-capturing group. Like so `$str = preg_replace('/(?:[?#&%=]).+/', '', $str);`